# Diffeomorphism group and isometry group of spheres $S^d$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, isometry, diffeomorphism

Let us consider a standard metric and differentiable structure on  $S^d$.

We first consider the diffeomorphism group and isometry group of $S^2$ or $S^d$ on itself.

**1. What is the diffeomorphism group of $S^2$ or $S^d$?**

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism),
the diffeomorphism group of $S^2$ has the homotopy-type of the subgroup $O(3)$. This was proven by Steve Smale.

- What does exactly "the homotopy-type of the subgroup $(3)$" mean?

So is the answer $$Diff(S^2)=O(3)?$$

Is the answer true in general for $$Diff(S^d)=O(d+1)?$$
at least for the standard sphere not the exotic spheres?

**2. What is the isometry group of $S^2$ or $S^d$?** Every isometry group of a metric space is a subgroup of isometries. According to [Isometries of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27418/isometries-of-the-sphere-mathbbsn), it seems that
$$Isometry(S^d)=O(d+1)?$$
in general.

Therefore, is that
$$Diff(S^d)=Isometry(S^d)?$$

Comment: The diffeomorphism and isometry groups are *never* the same in dimension $>0$. The diffeomorphism group is much larger (infinite dimensional, in fact). That they have the same homotopy type just means that there is a homotopy equivalence between them.

Comment: "The homotopy-type of $X$" means "the equivalence class of $X$ under the equivalence relation of homotopy equivalence".

Comment: See my answer to [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147793/diffeomorphism-group-and-isometry-group-of-torus-t2) for a proof that for all Riemannian manifolds $X$ of dimension $\ge 1$, $\text{Diff}(X) \ne \text{Isometry}(X)$.